# Dynamic Linq Library to generate particular type object for selected properties

Tags: linq

Im using Dynamic LINQ Library for my Application, In the sample of Dynamic LINQ Library, 
We can pass string of Comma separated columns name or property names to select clause of LINQ 
like below
.Select("new (AccountingDocumentNbr,DocumentFiscalYearNbr)");

Can we pass some object to instantiate and populate property values into the object like below

.Select("new AccountingObject(AccountingDocumentNbr,DocumentFiscalYearNbr)");

AccountingObject will have AccountingDocumentNbr,DocumentFiscalYearNbr. Is it possible to do it with Dynamic LINQ Library .
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Need your inputs on this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in theory your code should looks something like this:

```
Function ParseNew() As Expression
    NextToken()
    ValidateToken(TokenId.OpenParen, Res.OpenParenExpected)
    NextToken()
    Dim properties As New List(Of DynamicProperty)()
    Dim expressions As New List(Of Expression)()
    Do
        Dim exprPos = tokenVal.pos
        Dim expr = ParseExpression()
        Dim propName As String
        If TokenIdentifierIs("as") Then
            NextToken()
            propName = GetIdentifier()
            NextToken()
        Else
            Dim [me] As MemberExpression = TryCast(expr, MemberExpression)
            If [me] Is Nothing Then Throw ParseError(exprPos, Res.MissingAsClause)
            propName = [me].Member.Name
        End If
        expressions.Add(expr)
        properties.Add(New DynamicProperty(propName, expr.Type))
        If tokenVal.id <> TokenId.Comma Then Exit Do
        NextToken()
    Loop
    ValidateToken(TokenId.CloseParen, Res.CloseParenOrCommaExpected)
    NextToken()
    Dim type As Type = If(newResultType, DynamicExpression.CreateClass(properties))
    Dim bindings(properties.Count - 1) As MemberBinding
    For i As Integer = 0 To bindings.Length - 1
        bindings(i) = Expression.Bind(type.GetProperty(properties(i).Name), expressions(i))
    Next
    Return Expression.MemberInit(Expression.[New](type), bindings)
End Function
```

But how are you calling the Select method? It should looks more or less like this:

```
 .Select<ObjectHolder>("new (Activity as Activity, ActivityName as ActivityName)")
```

Comment: Hi Haris, Dynamic Linq Library doesnot accept .Select<T>. we cannot pass type next to select clause. Should I change the code according to above in Dynamic Linq Library